# cx_Oracle with Windows authentication

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, windows-authentication, cx-oracle

I would like to make cx_Oracle work with Windows OS authentication but fail miserably:

1. I know that with pyodbc you can make it work using `trusted_connection='yes'` but I have to make use of the Oracle client (11g/12c), which does not seem to go well in hand with pyodbc.
2. The closest to what I need seems to be the use of [Wallets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485145/authentication-with-public-keys-and-cx-oracle-using-python). However, duplicating existing information does not seem like the way to go.
3. There is mention of external authentication in the [cx_Oracle 5.2.1 release notes](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html) but this also seems related to wallets.

I hope that some clever person out there can point me in the right direction, thanks :)

Comment: What code did you try? External authentication is not only for wallets!

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga: Embarassingly enough I never tried the most obvious: `cx_Oracle.connect('','',<SERVICE_NAME>)` with SERVICE_NAME from tnsnames.ora. This works out of the box. Thank you for forcing me to give it one more shot :)

Comment: No problem. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For external authentication with cx_Oracle, the code to use is as simple as this:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn="the_tns_entry_name")
```