# Getting current userid and password in windows

Tags: python-3.x, authentication

I am logged into windows 10 where I am trying to run a connection to oracle db as:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
qry = 'select * from Table11 where rownum < 20'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('uid', 'pwd', 'myDBOracle')
testData = pd.read_sql(qry, conn)
```

The username and password for the database `myDBOracle` is same as my windows authentication. However, windows authentication changes every month. So, I was wondering whether there was a way to recover the current authentication password for windows so that I don't have to worry about my query breaking every month after password change; since the windows authentication change flows to database also.

I am currently doing:

```
import os
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(os.getlogin(), 'pwd', 'myDBOracle')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your DB user account was created with `IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY` (see [external authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/DBSEG/configuring-authentication.htm#GUID-37BECE32-58D5-43BF-A098-97936D66968F)), then connect with:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn = "the_tns_entry_name")
```

See [cx_Oracle with Windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020986/cx-oracle-with-windows-authentication)